# Get SUM value in Object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query in hibernate that SUM two fields. But i don't know how to get the value in Object given List commandclient2.

This is the query

```
List commandeclient2 = getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<List>() {
        @Override
        public List doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
            Query query = session.createQuery(
                    "SELECT SUM(pafd) as pafds, SUM(pmdm) as pmdms FROM Commandeclient c WHERE c.modepayement IS NOT NULL AND c.montantpaye IS NOT NULL"
            );
            return query.list();
        }
    });
```

I already try to use, but it gives Object

```
commandeclient2.get(0)
```

Comment: Did you check what is the type of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have as a result

```
List<Object[]> commandeclient2

for(Object[] client : commandeclient2) {
    client[0] //SUM(pafd)   
    client[1] //SUM(pmdm)
}
```